# Can't explode string after file upload

Tags: php, file, laravel, laravel-4, vcf-vcard

I have an upload system on my site, where you can upload vcards. I also wrote a vcard parser, that will put the right fields in the database.

Only thing is, when I upload my vcard (using laravel), I cannot explode the files contents.

```
    foreach (Input::file('vcards', array()) as $vcard)
    {
        if ($vcard->guessExtension() !== 'vcf')
        {
            continue;
        }

        $filename = uniqid() . '.vcf';

        $vcard->move(storage_path('vcards'), $filename);

        $contacts = array_filter(explode('BEGIN:VCARD', file_get_contents(storage_path("vcards/$filename"))));
    }
```

$contacts is a one count array, and it is the filestring. After some testing I found out, that if I just do explode('B', $fileContents); of any other letter in that string. It will explode the given string.

I also tried this on my server to see if it had maybe something to do with my computer, but the same problem appears.

I also tried to cut the string up (maybe it was too big), also didn't work.

Later I noticed that another vcard was working, but the other one wasn't is there maybe some kind of string encoding that I should try before parsing it?

Comment: `if (!$vcard->guessExtension() === 'vcf')` seems strange, shouldn't it be `if ($vcard->guessExtension() !== 'vcf')`?

Comment: yeah i know, tricky but it does work. also with your syntax

Comment: and it is false, so it will continue after that, corrected it :), but it doesnt help with this problem

Answer (score 2):

Is "explode()" case sensitive?  The vCard standard says that "BEGIN" can be any case (although in practice, it is almost *always* uppercase).  I would check the case of the characters in the "BEGIN" property to make sure they are uppercase for every vCard.  Also, check for spaces around the colon.

Comment: tried spaces too, but the only that triggers are the single characters like just B or just E or just a colon.